# Using ionic 3 facebook login with spring backend

Tags: spring, facebook, ionic-framework, authentication, authorization

I do realise similiar questions have been asked, but I could not make it work with answers to them, please try and help my specific case.

I am developing a hybrid mobile app with latest version of ionic. I want the users to log-in to the app with facebook and with facebook only - no other account creation involved.

The reason I want to connect the app with facebook is that I want to get access to to users' facebook friends who also use the app.

Apart from that I want to create a server side api for that app, using spring or spring boot. I want to do that in order to store some information that the user and his friends using the app can manipulate in the app.

I have implemented the app facebook login using the `cordova-plugin-facebook4` . So now I can login to my ionic app using facebook and make requests to the facebook graph API. However, I would like to now make calls to my own API to retrieve info about my friends that I have stored in my db, say to `myapi.com/getInfo?friendId={someFacebookUserId}`.

How can I make sure that I can make that request and receive a response ONLY if I am logged in with my account and `{someFacebookUserId}` is in fact my facebook friend? In other words, please help me authenticate my backend API with the same token or whatever, that my client (the ionic app) is currently authroized with. What is the best way to do it?